# Can't install Magento theme

Tags: theme, installation, magento2.3

After having to download the theme into my Magento root I run command **php bin/magento setup: upgrade** and I meet that error:

> **Magento supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements.html**

I don't understand why this error comes, maybe because my PHP version is  7.2.11..
 Please help me .thanks.

Comment: What version of Magento are you running?

Comment: yeah try changing your PHP version to 7.1.x

Comment: magento version 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Your cli PHP version may be different than the one used in HTTP requests (configured in Apache / Nginx)

What you need to do is first check your cli PHP version by running `php -v` and if it's less than 7.0 you need to change it. Depending on your operating system, there are different methods to do that.

For example, on Ubuntu, you need to run the following command:
`sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0`

On Windows, it depends on what WAMP application you are using. You should check the application documentation

Comment: my php CLI version is 5.6 ... im working in local and i use laragon

Comment: Ok, and have you tried changing the CLI PHP version?

Comment: yes of course, i have to upgrade my CLI PHP version , can you help me?

Comment: ok, so if you run `php -v` in your console, and get a version > 7.0, do you still have issues running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` ? If yes, what is the new issue?